Trying to avoid hard coding and figure out how to automatically retrieve latest AWS credentials in Python AWS S3 uploader script
My company has a bunch of files in our on-premise file server and I need to get them uploaded into AWS S3 buckets. The credentials to access these buckets are stored in AWS Secrets where they get updated automatically every 60 days.  I have written a Python script that will upload files to a bucket. It works by keeping the AWS access key and AWS secret key hard-coded in Windows Credential Manager, and every 60 days when the credentials expire I manually log onto AWS Secrets and grab the new values and copy-paste them into WCM.
What I am trying to avoid, is having a process with hard-coded credentials or having to make a manual update every so often. What would be ideal is if the credentials could somehow automatically be retrieved when they get updated.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I might go about tackling this? The Python script to upload to S3 is being run on a Windows Server 2019 machine. Please let me know if you need any additional information from me to assist in troubleshooting or brainstorming.
Tried hard coding AWS access key and secret access key into Windows Credential Manager.
Thank you!

It would probably be best to directly retrieve the credentials from AWS Secrets Manager without using Windows Credential Manager.
Option 1: IAM User with necessary permissions

Create an IAM User for the "upload computer"
Store the credentials on that computer with the AWS CLI aws configure command
Grant that IAM User permission to upload to S3

Then, your upload program can simply access S3 without having to retrieve any particular credentials. Access is granted via the IAM User.
Option 2: IAM User that grabs credentials from AWS Secrets Manager

Create an IAM User for the "upload computer"
Store the credentials on that computer with the AWS CLI aws configure command
Grant that IAM User permission to access the appropriate secrets in AWS Secrets Manager

Then, when your upload program runs, it first retrieve the credentials from AWS Secrets Manager and use those credentials to upload to S3.

Is there a way to implement this solution that doesn't involve having credentials stored in plaintext in the awsconfig file when at rest?

Instead of storing the IAM User credentials in the ~/.aws/credentials file, you could store them in the Windows Credentials Manager and your upload program could retrieve them and use them directly or put them in Environment Variables so that the AWS CLI an access them. The benefit is that the IAM User credentials won't need to rotate every 60 days.
